# PHP if mail sends, go to success page, if not go to fail page

Tags: php, email, phpmailer

First off, thank you to all who have helped in the past with questions.
I've got a PHP webpage that submits an application form to an email address, and at the end I have an IF function to send the user to either success.html if the email sends, or error.html if not.

Whether the email sends or not, the user is always taken to error.html

My code is as follows:

```
    require '/PHPMailer-master/PHPMailerAutoload.php';
    require '/PHPMailer-master/class.phpmailer.php';

    $mail = new PHPMailer;

    if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
        $to = "me@mymail.com";
        $from = $_POST['text_96'];
        $fullname = $_POST['text_95'];
        $email = $_POST['text_96'];
        $dob = $_POST['date_12'];
        $addr = $_POST['textarea_31'];
        $maths = $_POST['text_93'];
        $english = $_POST['text_31'];
        $holidayst = $_POST['date_74'];
        $holidayend = $_POST['date_91'];
        $distance = $_POST['number_58'];
        $awayhome = $_POST['selectlist_90'];

        foreach($_POST['checkbox'] as $key=>$val){$apprent .= $val.' ';}
        //$fileatt = $_POST['file'];
        $reasontext = $_POST['textarea_60'];
        $message = "Message";

        $mail->setFrom($from, $fullname);
        $mail->addAddress('me@mymail.com');
        $mail->addAttachment($_FILES['file']['name']); 

        if (isset($_FILES['file']) &&
        $_FILES['file']['error'] == UPLOAD_ERR_OK) {
        $mail->AddAttachment($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'],
                     $_FILES['file']['name']);
        }

        $mail->Subject = 'subject';
        $mail->Body    = $message;

    if(!$mail->send()) {
        $message = NULL;
        $headers = NULL;
        header('Location: success.html');
    } else {
        $message = NULL;
        $headers = NULL;
        header('Location: error.html');
    }
```

I'm using PHPMailer to send the emails when a button is clicked.
The part I'm having trouble with is the following:

```
    if(!$mail->send()) {
        $message = NULL;
        $headers = NULL;
        header('Location: success.html');
    } else {
        $message = NULL;
        $headers = NULL;
        header('Location: error.html');
    }
```

I hope this make sense, please let me know if you need any further information.
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: `if(!$mail->send()) {` means that it failed (the `!`). So you probably need to remove that. What is your exact problem though, what happens - or doesn't happen?

Comment: I think you have to invert condition: `if( $mail->send() ) {success} else {error} ` (remove exclamation point)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Shouldn't it be:

```
if($mail->send()) {
        $message = NULL;
        $headers = NULL;
        header('Location: success.html');
    } else {
        $message = NULL;
        $headers = NULL;
        header('Location: error.html');
    }
```

?

$mail->send() returns true in case of a success, not the opposite.

Comment: How did I overlook this? Honestly! Fresh set of eyes always does it, eh? Thank you for your help :)

Answer (score 0):

According to the source code for PHPMailer (https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/blob/master/class.phpmailer.php) the send() method will return false on error or true if it was successfully sent. Looking at your code you are sending users to the success.html page when send() returns false

In your code change:

```
if(!$mail->send()) {
    $message = NULL;
    $headers = NULL;
    header('Location: success.html');
```

To (i.e remove the "!")

```
if($mail->send()) {
    $message = NULL;
    $headers = NULL;
    header('Location: success.html');
```

You should also wrap the call to send() in a try {} catch {} block to catch any exceptions it might throw so you can still control sending the user to your error page.

Comment: It's also [documented](http://phpmailer.github.io/PHPMailer/classes/PHPMailer.html#method_send). PHPMailer only throws exceptions if you enable them by passing `true` to the constructor.

Answer (score 0):

This should work for you.

```
require '/PHPMailer-master/PHPMailerAutoload.php';
require '/PHPMailer-master/class.phpmailer.php';

$mail = new PHPMailer(true);

if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    $to = "me@mymail.com";
    $from = $_POST['text_96'];
    $fullname = $_POST['text_95'];
    $email = $_POST['text_96'];
    $dob = $_POST['date_12'];
    $addr = $_POST['textarea_31'];
    $maths = $_POST['text_93'];
    $english = $_POST['text_31'];
    $holidayst = $_POST['date_74'];
    $holidayend = $_POST['date_91'];
    $distance = $_POST['number_58'];
    $awayhome = $_POST['selectlist_90'];

    foreach($_POST['checkbox'] as $key=>$val){$apprent .= $val.' ';}
    //$fileatt = $_POST['file'];
    $reasontext = $_POST['textarea_60'];
    $message = "Message";

    $mail->setFrom($from, $fullname);
    $mail->addAddress('me@mymail.com');
    $mail->addAttachment($_FILES['file']['name']); 

    if (isset($_FILES['file']) &&
    $_FILES['file']['error'] == UPLOAD_ERR_OK) {
    $mail->AddAttachment($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'],
                 $_FILES['file']['name']);
    }

    $mail->Subject = 'subject';
    $mail->Body    = $message;
    try{
        $mail->send()) {
        header('Location: success.html');
    }catch(Exception $e)
    {
        header('Location: error.html');
    }
    finally{
        $message = NULL;
        $headers = NULL;
    }
}
```